# Helvetica has no Unicode support flutter Using Pdf package

Tags: flutter, pdf-generation

i am trying to use pdf in my flutter project but getting error

> Helvetica has no Unicode support see https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/wiki/Fonts-Management

i just copy the sample from the flutter package page and got this error
i tried to use fonts from the local assets file also but didn't work
basically i have no idea what i need to do and what i am doing so please guide me

Comment: Helvitica has no Unicode support is just a suggestion it is not an Error(I used to thought because since the day i started use of pdf package it shows only this message Never show the pdf which i was expecting ) The error was in OpenFile as when i used PdfViewer Package it showed me the result

Answer (score 4):

I think you used a non unicoded font in a widget and try to generate a pdf includes it. You need to add this family to your project to use in pdf.
Add your font family to your pubspec.yaml file. Should find Helvetica family.

```
  fonts:
- family: Montserrat
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/open-sans.ttf
```

Get in code and pass it to your pdf.something widget generator.

```
final font = await rootBundle.load("assets/open-sans.ttf");
final ttf = Font.ttf(font);

pdf.addPage(Page(
    build: (Context context) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('Dart is awesome', style: TextStyle(font: ttf, fontSize: 40)),
      ); // Center
    }));
```

Reference : [also_check_the_link](https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/issues/196)

Comment: i already cloned this referenced file The error has gone but now nothing is happening when button is pressed please you check it by yourself and if it work then please share the file again thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

Helvitica has no Unicode support is just a suggestion it is not an Error(I used to thought because since the day i started use of pdf package it shows only this message Never show the pdf which i was expecting ) The error was in OpenFile(in my view) as when i used PdfViewer Package it showed me the desired pdf file

Answer (score 0):

Please use it like this in the example

```
final font = await PdfGoogleFonts.nunitoExtraLight();
```

reference : https://pub.dev/packages/printing/example